# Used ' Use Safe Area Layout Guides' with image in center of view. view is shifted to left

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

[Attached screenshot, Blue is View of ViewController.]I want to support for iPhoneX & IOS from 10 - 11+.
I select ' Use Safe Area Layout Guides' option. Added image view in center & set layout constraint with Safe area.
& run on simulator/ device both. View is displaying shifted to left side

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: I don't see any screenshot please update your question with one

Comment: i think you want to check your storyboard controller there you see some warning(constraint related) set them properly than you will show as well as you set.

Comment: and show your code, don't just describe your problem..

Comment: it is not enough information...

Comment: If following RB GujjuBoys' comment didn't help, then we need more information about constraints you've set